# How to exclude a specific id from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array with sports names, with the option to check and uncheck them.

The items with `checked = false` are being saved in a DB. By default all the items are in `checked = true`, BUT, I want to exclude one of the items in the array and put it to `checked = false` instead.

at first, the array looks like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 26,
    "name": "LIVE Betting",
    "priority": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "NBA",
    "priority": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "College Basketball",
    "priority": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 42,
    "name": "Women College Basketball",
    "priority": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "NHL",
    "priority": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "MLB",
    "priority": 5
  }
 ]
```

and this is the function working over here

```
_this.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
    var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
        intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);
    if (sports.length) {
        //HERE I NEED TO EXCLUDE THE ID 9
        sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
          sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
          return sport;
     });
    }
 });
```

which returns this objects

```
{
  "id": 26,
  "name": "LIVE Betting",
  "priority": 0,
  "checked": true
}
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "NBA",
  "priority": 1,
  "checked": true
}
{
  "id": 24,
  "name": "College Basketball",
  "priority": 2,
  "checked": true
}
{
  "id": 42,
  "name": "Women College Basketball",
  "priority": 3,
  "checked": true
}
{
  "id": 9,
  "name": "NHL",
  "priority": 4,
  "checked": true
}
{
  "id": 6,
  "name": "MLB",
  "priority": 5,
  "checked": true
}
```

so as you can see all those items are `checked = true` by default, but I want to set up the `id = 9` to `checked = false` by default until the user switches it to true in case that he wants.

What are your suggestions here? read the note in my code please, there is the part where I need to exclude it.

Comment: `_.findWhere(sports, { id: 9 }).checked = false`?

Comment: @Malk how can I include that in my code ? I tried already but it is not working

Comment: You are building a list of sports with a checkbox. You want the list to show NHL (id:9) checked, but not include it as if it was unchecked? Isn't that rather unexpected behaviour? Maybe you should build it unchecked to begin with?

Comment: @Malk all the elements on the list are checked = true by default once you log in, and that is right, but I want to set the ( id: 9 )  to unchecked by default.

Comment: How is the HTML generated?

Comment: ```<ion-item ng-repeat="sport in sports" ng-click="toggleSportSelection(sport)"> {{:: sport.name}}  </ion-item>``` @Malk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73110/discussion-between-malk-and-nietzscheprogrammer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can simply find the sport by id and uncheck it manually.

```
if (sports.length) {
    //HERE I NEED TO EXCLUDE THE ID 9
    sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
      sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
      // Special case for id 9
      if (sport.id === 9) {
        sport.checked = false;
      }
      return sport;
 }
```